# Java jdbc preparedstatements how can I check for empty row

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am implementing a forgot_password type feature on my application and I can not find how to check if I have any rows returned. The user first enters his/her email and then I search the database if the email is found proceed otherwise stop and tell them their email has not been found; This is my code

```
           Connection dbConnection=null;


                    dbConnection= DB.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement= dbConnection.prepareStatement("Select email,password from profiles where email=?");
                preparedStatement.setString(1, User_Email);
           preparedStatement.executeQuery();
// This code is not working below empty null rows still say email found
 if(preparedStatement==null)           
{
    return ok("Email not found");
}
else
{
 return ok("Email Found");
 }
```

The User_Email string works correctly and I have verified but it seems that

**preparedStatement==null** does nothing

Comment: You need to check the return value of executeQuery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the return with executeQuery() in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23986348/how-to-get-the-return-with-executequery-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nah, you're going about it the wrong way. `executeQuery()` returns a `ResultSet`. You just need to check if ResultSet has rows.

```
    ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    if (rs.next()) {
         //example
        String email = rs.getString(1);
        String pw = rs.getString(2);
    }
    else{
         //no results!!
    }
```